# Converting Character[] to String

Tags: java, arrays, character

What is the best way to convert a `Character[]` to `char[]` or a `String` ?

One way is to manually loop through the Character array presently in a `for(char c : CharacterArray)` loop , appending to a `StringBuilder`. `StringBuilder` seems to accept a `Character[]` directly also , but is that all to it ?

Comment: @jleedev : Think of me as a type-safety nut :-)

Comment: @Bhaskar, there is almost never a good reason to use a `Character[]` The best thing to do is to refactor your code so you don't have one in the first place. Use a `char[]` or a `StringBuilder` instead.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: I have a generic type in which one generic type param has to be 'char' - I dont know any other way to handle this other than using a Character , which then lands me in the situation mentioned.

Comment: @Bhaskar, Instead of List<Character> you should use StringBuilder. What type of generic collection are you using?

Comment: @Peter Lawrey : Its a Map<Character,Integer>. I am analyzing text/words and storing the letters-freq map, to be processed further by other code.

Comment: @Bhaskar, That makes sense, except the keys are in a pseudo random order so it wouldn't makes sense to take those keys and turn them into a String.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

commons-lang has a [toPrimitive method](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html#toPrimitive%28java.lang.Character%5B%5D%29), but there's nothing like this in the standard API. The only way is to loop through the array and transform each Character into a char (and decide what to do with null values).

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend converting the `Character[]` to a `char[]` using a simple loop and then passing it into new `String();`

```
    Character[] characters = new Character[128];
    char[] chars = new char[characters.length];
    int length = characters.length;
    for(int i=0; i<length; i++) {
        chars[i] = characters[i].charValue();
    }
    String string = new String(chars);
```

Another alternative would be to create a `StringBuilder` and loop through and add each character individually.

```
    Character[] characters = new Character[128];
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(characters.length);
    for(Character c : characters) {
        sb.append(c);
    }
    String string = sb.toString();
```

I have a feeling the first approach might be more efficient, but I'm not sure.

Comment: If you initialize the `StringBuilder` with enough capacity, the second way should be efficient.

Comment: True, the first one is much faster. The `StringBuilder` will each time recreate a new buffer of one character bigger than the previous one. I checked the Java source code of `StringBuilder`. Except when you construct the StringBuilder with the given size of the array. Then, there is no need for recreating the buffer. Then the performance will be the same.

Comment: actually if you do `new StringBuilder(characters.length);` it will be the most efficient if the appends and unboxing are inlined by JIT as the underlying char[] in the builder will be used in the resulting String

Comment: Foreach is less efficient than the standard for loop.  Also String uses StringBuilder as its implementation so String+= does not have a negative performance.

Comment: @All I updated to add the length to constructor of StringBuilder.  Thanks for the suggestion.